# Clarification of a theorem from Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-explanation

The following is from page 82 of Dummit and Foote's Abstract Algebra, 3rd edition.

Theorem 6 ((1) and (5)) says that a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal if and only if $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$. 
By definition, a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$ is normal if $gNg^{-1}=N$ for all $g\in G$. So does this theorem mean $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$ if and only if $gNg^{-1}=N$ for all $g\in G$?

Or more specifically, dose $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$ imply $N\subseteq gNg^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Since a group is closed under inversion, $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ for all $g$ iff $g^{-1}Ng \subset N$ for all $g$.

Comment: Thank you. So is it correct that $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ for all $g\in G$ does imply $N\subseteq gNg^{-1}$ for all $g\in G$? Basically what the part 1 and 5 of this theorem is saying is that to show $N$ is normal, it is enough to show only one inclusion $gNg^{-1}\subseteq N$ instead of $gNg^{-1}=N$?

Comment: Yes what you say is correct.  The argument in full could be phrased by saying that if one of the following holds for all $g \in G$, then they all do: (a) $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ (b)  $g^{-1}Ng \subset N$ (c) $Ng \subset gN$ (d) $N \subset gNg^{-1}$.    

Since $(a)$ and $(d)$ together imply $gNg^{-1}  = N$, we conclude part (5) of your theorem.  This is not a deep statement, but it does make life a smidge easier.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

I'll write out the answer in more detail.

Assume (*) $gNg^{-1} \subset N$ for all $g$.

Let $h \in N$ be arbitrary.

Now fix $g$.  By (*) $g^{-1}hg \in N$.  So then $h = g(g^{-1}hg)g^{-1} \in gNg^{-1}$.  Since $h$ was arbitrary, this implies that $N \subset gNg^{-1}$, so in fact $N = gNg^{-1}$

Answer (score 0):

The whole crux of the matter lies in showing:

If $gNg^{-1} \subseteq N$ for all $g \in G$, then $N \subseteq gNg^{-1}$ for any $g \in G$.

The way I always like to do this is pick any old $n \in N$. Then pick any old $g \in G$. Then we need to find some $n'\in N$, such that:

$n = gn'g^{-1}$.

So I am going to start with $n$, and then pick $g^{-1}$, which is certainly SOME element of $G$. So by our assumption, it follows that:

$g^{-1}n(g^{-1})^{-1} = g^{-1}ng \in N$.

So, let $n' = g^{-1}ng$.

Then $n = ene = ene^{-1} = (gg^{-1})n(gg^{-1})^{-1} = (gg^{-1})n(gg^{-1}) = g(g^{-1}ng)g^{-1} = gn'g^{-1}$.